# How does perf collect kernel space performance events?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, intel-pmu

What HW feature does `perf` use to collect performance monitoring event for ring 0 on Intel CPUs?

My picture of the world is this:

1. Looking for a free `IA32_PERFEVTSELn` MSR by asking `IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_INUSE`
2. When taking a free `IA32_PERFEVTSELn` it sets the dedicated bit for a particular counter that is being programmed for the MSR as depicted in the Intel Documentation, Vol.3.

[image]

Having said that either ring 0 or ring 3 or both are the only possible scenarios.

Comment: Yes, the `OS` and `USR` bits are set as requested.  Are you asking what the `perf` program is asking these bits to be set to? According to the manual you can specify suffix `:u` for user, `:k` for kernel or `:uk` for both.

Comment: @Jester Not really, I was actually interested in how those `:u` and `:k` worked under the hood. I mean I wanted to get a bit more details of the source of counters perf returns for kernel space code.

Comment: They work by passing the flag to the kernel which then sets the bits in the register. Still not quite sure what you need but look in `linux/arch/x86/events/intel`. You can see stuff like `if (!event->attr.exclude_kernel) config |= ARCH_PERFMON_EVENTSEL_OS;`

Comment: @Jester Yes, [that's](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/arch/x86/events/intel/bts.c#L229) exactly what I was looking for.